# How do I add a database constraint in a Many-to-Many Relation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class School(models.Model):
    principal = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The `User` model is Django's stock auth model. I want to only allow a school.principal to be instances of the `User` model that belongs to the Principals group. (By group, I also mean Django's stock auth `Group` model).

I'm basically stuck on how the implementation of check should be:

```
class School(models.Model):
    principal = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=<allow_only_User_instances_that_belongs_to_the_Principals_group>,
                name='principal_is_actually_a_principal',
            ),
        ]
```

On the chance that a database/Django version specific implementation is necessary, I'm using the following stack:

- Python 3.8
- Django 3.1
- PostgreSQL 12.1

I know I can add the check on the application level, but having database constraints makes me feel confident that my data is always in valid state. Any help or nudge to the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer : this is impossible.

If I understand well, you want to extend the User table with a Principal table, but you only want User that belongs to Group "principal" to be able to have such extension.
I guess the idea is to leave the User and Group tables untouched and provide additionnal data for "principal" users.

The nature of foreign keys won't let you do this. They operate on a single colum at a time and don't have "join" mechanism, neither filter, which means you can't ask for "GroupUser"->"Group"->only with "principal" name.

At some point you will have to create a table only containing users of the principal group if you want to leverage foreign keys. You would have to use triggers, which in turn will defeat the purpose of using forein keys : you could directly remove or create Principal rows without relying on a "PrincipalUser" table.

I don't know about triggers within your framework but it would be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you. It does seem like I have to resolve to applying the constraint at the application level.